# CMUSphinx for python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, wav, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

I've used cmu's pocketsphinx to convert a wav file into text. The wav file has an English conversation throughout. When used the pocketsphinx_continuous with hmm, lm and dict (en-us model), the converted text has no match with the wav file content. Am I missing something? Please throw some light on this. If anybody wants more details, I can give you the wav file as well as the converted text.

Comment: Such questions are better asked on cmusphinx forums, this resource is for programming questions. You need to share the file to get help on this issue. Most likely reason is the mismatched format. The audio must be 16khz 16bit mono.

Comment: thanks @NikolayShmyrev